# How to delete a property from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

When I use analytics.google.com to manage my web properties, I can only add new properties, but not delete them.

I tried data-deletion request, but that seems not applicable.

There is a big blue + button, but no delete. How can I delete a property?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Property Settings there is a button in the top right that says, "Move to bin."

[image: Screenshot of Analytics Property Settings]

That's how you delete a property in GA4. Universal Analytics properties have something similar, but the button says, "Move to Rubbish Bin" also on the Property Settings screen.